# Suppose that $f/g$ is a rational function on an integral scheme $X$, which we know to be locally regular. Then is $f/g$ regular?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I guess the answer to this question depends on what one means precisely by a rational function on an integral scheme.

I am a little bit confused about that myself, and I am worried that there is something subtle I might be missing.

Some googling has shown me that this is a tricky notion on non-integral schemes, so I just want to restrict myself to the integral case.

Let me try to give several possible definitions:

1. A rational function is in element in the stalk of the sheaf of regular functions of $X$. (X is integral.) This seems to be the same as defining a rational function as one that is a section of the structure sheaf over an open set, modulo the usual equivalence relationship of agreeing on a smaller open set. This can be described as a skyscraper sheaf valued in this set over the generic point.
2. A rational function is an element of the sheafification of the presheaf $U \to Frac (O_X(U))$. Is sheafification necessary? Certainly the presheaf is different, for example the only global sections of this presheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$ are $k$, which isn't the correct notion of rational function. I think when you sheafify you get basically the skyscraper sheaf in part 1, since on any two affine opens the localization to distinguished opens in their overlap give identical rings.

Question 1: Are these the correct notions? Are these all the same? (Hopefully, the second question is a logical consequence of the first.)

About the question the title:

With definition 1, I am not completely sure what it would mean for it to be locally regular. I guess this means that every point $p$ would have a neighborhood $U$ with the property that there is a regular function $h \in O_X(U)$ that restricted to $f/g$ in stalk of the generic point. Since $X$ is integral, and therefore reduced, so that sections agreeing on an open are equal (in this case the open is some smaller neighborhood of the generic point), this definition implies that there is a global regular function whose stalk at the generic point is $f/g$.

With definition 2, I *guess* one could check that the ring of global sections is a subsheaf of the sheaf of rational functions - again this follows from regularity of $X$, which will imply that the maps over each open are injections. In this case I can prove my question in the following way: if I took a rational function and restricted to opens on which it was regular then (since there is a unique global gluing which we know is a regular) the original rational function is regular.

Question 2: Are these claims correct?

Question 3: What is the right way to define a rational function (on an integral scheme)? Is my original question true in that context? (What about more general definitions of rational functions?)

Finally, the conclusion I want to draw is this - the ring of global sections of a normal scheme is integrally closed in its field of fractions. An integral fraction and its minimal polynomial will restrict to integral fractions and their minimal polynomials on the opens sets of some affine cover, proving that the restrictions of that fraction are regular, hence that the original fraction was a global section.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See Exercise II.3.6 of Hartshorne. For integral schemes, the sheaf you define in part 2 is a constant sheaf, since on affine opens $Frac(\mathcal{O}_X(U))$ always gives the same thing, the function field. This is slightly different from the skyscraper sheaf you defined in part 1, since it is supported everywhere.

I believe all your claims are correct, except that I am not sure about the last one (global sections of normal schemes).

Comment: See also page 140-141 in Hartshorne, for the definition of the "sheaf of total quotient rings" on general schemes.

Comment: @JakeLevinson Thanks - I'll dig up my Hartshorne and take a look. About the support of the skyscraper sheaf - at least on an irreducible scheme, the generic point is in every open set, so it is defined everywhere... right?

Comment: Ah, you are right, my mistake. (I'm used to thinking of skyscraper sheaves at closed points...). Yes. (This is also in Hartshorne, exercise II.1.17.)